# Feeds file path to content type

Tags: 8, feeds

I’m using feed module to import csv file. and the content type includes file field. I added the external file path in the csv file (file column). but It's not working. 
Mapping includes:

```
Target:
Attachments: (field_file): File ID
Attachments: (field_file): Desciption

Feeds item: (feeds_item): item URL
Feeds item: (feeds_item): item GUID

Title(title)

csv:
ID
file
title
```

How I can deal with Attachments and Feeds item in source section. What I should put in the source section for Attachments and Feeds item.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your file field set to allow only one value? Can you visit the item URLs and actually download the files, are they accessible? You need to add a lot more info to your question to be able to be helped.

Answer (score 0):

Currently only files coming from a HTTP(s) source are supported in the D8 version of Feeds. So the sources for the files need to look like this:

- http://www.example.com/myfile.jpg
- http://www.example.com/myfile.pdf
- https://www.example.com/myfile.jpg
- https://www.example.com/myfile.pdf

Adding support for local file paths is planned:
https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds/issues/2968671

See also other file target related issues:
https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/search?issue_tags=Feeds%20file%20target